# Wine Windows Python Failing in Redirection

Tags: python, linux, wine

I am trying to run Windows python 3.8 from Linux Wine. It works fine in interactive mode. However, if it is redirected, it fails:

wine python -v -c "import os;print(os)" > output.txt

```
# Z:\WinePython\lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-38.pyc matches Z:\WinePython\lib\encodings\latin_1.py
# code object from 'Z:\\WinePython\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\latin_1.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000000007394C0>
# Z:\WinePython\lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-38.pyc matches Z:\WinePython\lib\io.py
# code object from 'Z:\\WinePython\\lib\\__pycache__\\io.cpython-38.pyc'
# Z:\WinePython\lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-38.pyc matches Z:\WinePython\lib\abc.py
# code object from 'Z:\\WinePython\\lib\\__pycache__\\abc.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000000739970>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000000007396A0>
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
OSError: [WinError 6] Invalid handle

Current thread 0x000000f6 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Since I am using an external wrapper of the process, I need it to work in redirection mode. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Have you read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328951/redirect-stdout-of-a-windows-command-line-program-under-wine ?

Comment: Does not seem to help